# Why does the command "group" in ggplot doesn't work?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library (tidyverse)
library (datarium)

data("anxiety", package = "datarium")    
   
anxiety <- anxiety %>%   
  rename(groupes = group)
  anxiety1 <- anxiety %>% 
   pivot_longer (c("t3", "t2", "t1"), names_to = "moment", 
                 values_to = "valeur") %>%   
   print ()
   
ggplot (data = anxiety1, aes (x = groupes, y = valeur,  
        colour = moment, group = moment)) +   
 geom_line () +   
 geom_point ()
```

The command "group" in ggplot2 doesn't work and give an awful chart.

Comment: Can you describe how it didn't work?  And maybe paste a line or two of the data frame so the issue can be reproduced

Answer (score 1):

If you keep `groupes` on the x axis, there is no way to have lines going across the page, since each individual `id` only belongs to a single group.
The lines would therefore all be vertical.

In your version, you have joined the dots of all individuals at a particular `moment` by setting `moment` as the grouping variable. This will join all the dots for each color in each `moment`, then zig-zag to the next point on the x axis, which looks ugly. However, this is exactly what setting `group = moment` is asking `ggplot` to do.

Instead, it makes more sense to have `moment` on the x axis, colour by `groupes`, and group by `id`:

```r
ggplot(data = anxiety1, 
       aes (x = moment, y = valeur, colour = groupes, group = id)) +   
  geom_line() +   
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would follow `@Allan Cameron` suggestion in this case. I managed to find the error. Basically is the way you save your result (name of the tibbles). I inserted the comments where I found the errors.

Sample code:

```
library (tidyverse)
library (datarium)

data("anxiety", package = "datarium")    
   
anxiety1 <- anxiety %>%   #name as anxiety1
  rename(groupes = group)

  anxiety2 <- anxiety1 %>%  # change name to anxiety2
   pivot_longer (c("t3", "t2", "t1"), names_to = "moment", 
                 values_to = "valeur") %>%   
   print ()
   
ggplot (data = anxiety2, aes (x = groupes, y = valeur,  colour = moment, group = moment)) +   # change to anxiety 2 
 geom_line () +   
 geom_point ()
```

Sample plot:

[image]